# What encoding conversion is done by "print" in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

As title.

my code:

```
print("中文")
```

error occur:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It seem `print` will first encode the unicode to bytes?
The `encode` depends on `sys.stdout.encoding`, so the problem solved by setting `PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8`

but when does it decode to unicode?

and how about bytes data? how does `print` bytes data?

Comment: From Python 3.4+ (or earlier, I don't quite recall right now), you can think of string in Python as an array/list of code points. When you print, you will encode the code point to bytes representation in the encoding as specified in `sys.stdout.encoding`

Comment: @nhahtdh yes, I aware that. But in terminal, the things show is unicode, when does it decode to unicode? which encoding it use? I want to know more detail